# Dynamic Linq/ Dynamic Query: cannot get data for jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, jqgrid, dynamic-linq

I'm using jqGrid and I have a problem getting Dynamic Linq to work. I used NuGet to install Dynamic and added "using System.Linq.Dynamic;".

Using VS 2010 Pro, MVC 3.0

This works:

```
var s = context.testdata;
var c = s.Count();
```

c shows 5136 items.

But I cannot get the dynamic approach to work:

```
var s = context.testdata.OrderBy("id asc");
```

I get this error message:

```
'id' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. 
Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, 
that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.
```

This however does work:

```
var s = (from ss in context.testdata
                      orderby ss.id
                      select ss).ToList();
var c = s.Count();
```

Again I get all 5136 items.

I've got the code from here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx
and here:
http://www.timdavis.com.au/code/jquery-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this `context.testdata.OrderBy("id")`

Comment: @Wahid: No, same error. But according to the demos of jqGrid asc or desc should work.

Comment: Try to add the the DynamicLibrary manually http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx

Comment: I tried it but I get the same error. I tried deleting the library and get the same error, I think the library is not used at all. What else is needed besides adding the lib and the using statement? The demos from the links above work fine for me. I even recreated a new simple db and model and still get the same. I also recreated my code from scratch and still get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution here:
[Strange Exception thrown using Dynamic Linq Entity Framework Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180487/strange-exception-thrown-using-dynamic-linq-entity-framework-query)

This works:

```
var s = context.testdata.OrderBy("it.id asc");
```